# Need help in creating SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with following schema and contains records-

```
id     parent_id    active
1      NULL           Y
2      1              Y
3      1              N
4      NULL           Y
5      4              N
6      NULL           N
7      6              N
```

I need to write a SQL for following use case:

Need to find all records whose active not equals to Y and whose parent_id active equals to Y.

Example output of above should be as follows:

output should be-

```
id     parent_id    active
3      1              N
5      4              N
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: check my answer. I have attached working demo as well

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using self join as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytab t1 INNER JOIN mytab t2
ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
WHERE t1.active != 'Y'
AND   t2.active = 'Y'
```

Comment: This would not give me desired result, I need output for all ids whose active is not equal to Y but their respective parent_id active was Y. Please check question and desired output for given input

Comment: `join` condition is wrongly scripted. It needs to be `t1.parent_id=t2.id`. You can see it in my answer's fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

use subquery 1st take all the id's who have active=Y then check with parent_id and active column

```
 select * from tbale_name where 
 parent_id in (
  select id from table_name where active='Y'
     ) and active='N'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4a450a50a2ea6c3f4e1a19e2657ae35d

```
id  parent_id   active
3     1             N
5     4             N
```

Comment: This would not give me desired result, I need output for all ids whose active is not equal to Y but their respective parent_id active was Y

Comment: @AshishNagdev then why not id 7 in your output

Comment: 7 parent_id is 6 and its active is N that is not Y

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using self-join as following:

```
    select t1.id,t1.parent_id,t1.active
    from test t1 inner join test t2 on t1.parent_id=t2.id
    where t1.active <> 'Y' and t2.active='Y';
```

Results can be seen here:
[DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2e86d5287654619f3e7946d386040f51)